# err=23 when updating textboxes

Tags: python-3.x, qt5

I'm getting the following error when updating text boxes:

`load glyph failed err=23 face=0x0, glyph=19`

All of the lines responsible for updating the text boxes look like this the par:

`self.lnePer1_temp.setText(str(values_s[0]))# + " °C")`

The method which aggregates these methods is called like this:

```
def timer_handler(self):
    self.pressedSearchDevices()
    if self.grbKeys1.isEnabled():
        self.pressedKey1_bat()
    if self.grbKeys2.isEnabled():
        self.pressedKey2_bat()
    if self.grbPer1.isEnabled():
        self.pressedPer1_read_all()
    if self.grbPer2.isEnabled():
        self.pressedPer2_read_all()
    threading.Timer(60, lambda: self.timer_handler()).start()
```

Basically it checks periodically whether some devices are available and updates the textboxes accordingly. When commented out - everything works fine. The full method responsible for updating the textboxes is:

```
def pressedPer2_read_all(self):
    call('./reset_ble.sh', shell=True)
    cmd = "sudo node Per_read_all.js " + Per_2.lower()
    output = 'None'
    with Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid) as process:
        try:
            output = process.communicate(timeout=5)[0]
        except TimeoutExpired:
            os.killpg(process.pid, signal.SIGINT) # send signal to the process group
            output = process.communicate()[0]
    print(output)
    output_s = output.decode("utf-8")
    values_s = output_s.split('\n')
    for s in values_s: print(s + " °C")
    if len(values_s) == 7:
        self.lnePer2_temp.setText(str(values_s[0]))# + " °C")
        self.lnePer2_dig.setText(str(values_s[1]))
        self.lnePer2_light.setText(str(values_s[2]))# + " %")
        self.lnePer2_hum.setText(str(values_s[3]))# + " %")
        self.lnePer2_alert.setText(str(values_s[4]))
        self.lnePer2_but.setText(str(values_s[5]))
    else:
        self.lnePer2_temp.setText(" °C")
        self.lnePer2_dig.setText(" ")
        self.lnePer2_light.setText(" %")
        self.lnePer2_hum.setText(" %")
        self.lnePer2_alert.setText(" ")
        self.lnePer2_but.setText(" ")
```

When replacing the `if-else` statement with only the `else` statement - everything works fine, so I'm assuming that the error lies in the change of values or something like that. Similar error messages link to Qt, so I'm also assuming that the fault lies somewhere there.

The script is running on a Raspberry Pi Zero, the Python Version used is Python 3.4.2, the PyQt5 version is 5.3.2.

Comment: Please correct the indentation of your code, in python it is important.

Comment: You could also print values_s

Comment: @eyllanesc where is the indentation wrong? The values are printed in the for statement.